# Is Minecraft: Wii U Edition only available in Nintendo's eShop?

Tags: wii-u, minecraft-legacy-console

I prefer physical discs over downloadable, digital-only products. Can I get *Minecraft* for the Wii U as a physical disc? Or is it only available in Nintendo's eShop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to a [blog](http://nintendoenthusiast.com/news/minecraft-wii-u-edition-will-get-a-physical-release-at-a-later-date/) I've read this December 7, *Minecraft's* Wii U edition will be having its physical release on a "later date". As for now, it's only available through Nintendo's shop.

Comment: Do you have a link to this blog?

Comment: Sure. See my edited post